# HTML5 Audio iPAD, Cannot play audio file ?

Tags: ios, ipad, html, html5-audio

I got a little issue

I'm trying to play audio files on a webView with html5 on the ipad simulator, i got a code like this:

```
<audio controls="controls" format="mp3 ogg">
      <source src="test.ogg" />
       <source src="test.mp3" />
</audio>
```

But i always got a "cannot play audio file" on the black bar on control :/

Someone as an idea why ?

Of course my test.mp3 and test.ogg are added in my xcode project and are in the same directory

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Format attribute in audio doesn't makes any sense.
You should use type attribute in source tag.

See example:

```
<source src="test.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

This is working in ipad.

Comment: This works over HTTP but not over HTTPS on safari. Works fine in other browsers regardless of which protocol is used. Any ideas why?